# ¿Como agregar un formulario dentro de un jquery para que se guarde en una base de datos?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Es que un calendario que, al darle click a un dia este me muestre un formulario, y este pueda ingresar datos en el mismo para despues se puedan guardar los datos en la base de datos.

En la primera parte se muestra el calendario que es con el datepicker, despues, aparece el formulario que lo meti dentro de la alert. No se si haya una forma de que igual de alert aparezca como un pop.

Estaba intentando meter ese formulario a mi jquery con HTML pero, no se, si se pueda hacer de esa manera, y poder enviarlo a una base de datos, pero no me doy mucha idea de como hacerlo, me gustaria me pudieran ayudar.Ya busque algunos ejemplos pero ninguno me dice como hacerlo cuando de click y menos con jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Formulario con Ajax</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formdata">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"></br>
                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" required="required"></br>
                <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label><input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" required="required"></br>
                Género: <input type="radio" name="genero" id="hombre" checked="checked"><label for="hombre"> Hombre - </label><input type="radio" name="genero" id="mujer"><label for="mujer"> Mujer</label>
                <label for="mayor">Es mayor de 18 años: </label><input type="checkbox" name="mayor" id="mayor" required="required">
                <input type="button" id="botonenviar" value="Enviar"><
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="exito" style="display:none">
            Sus datos han sido recibidos con éxito.
        </div>
        <div id="fracaso" style="display:none">
            Se ha producido un error durante el envío de datos.
        </div>

 </body>
<script>
$( function() {
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                        changeMonth:true,
                        changeYear:true,
                        yearRange: "1990:2050", 
                        firstDay: 1,
                        minDate: 0,
                        
                         beforeShowDay: function (day) { 
                            var day = day.getDay(); 
                            if (day == 6 || day == 0) { 
                            return [false, "somecssclass"] 
                             } else { 
                                    return [true, "someothercssclass"] 
                                    } 
                            },
                          onSelect: function (date) {
                            alert(function validaForm(){
    // Campos de texto
    if($("#nombre").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Nombre no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#nombre").focus();       // Esta función coloca el foco de escritura del usuario en el campo Nombre directamente.
        return false;
    }
    if($("#apellidos").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Apellidos no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#apellidos").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if($("#direccion").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Dirección no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#direccion").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Checkbox
    if(!$("#mayor").is(":checked")){
        alert("Debe confirmar que es mayor de 18 años.");
        return false;
    }

    return true; // Si todo está correcto
})
                            },

                        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo',
                        'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
                        'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                        'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],

                        closeText: 'Cerrar',
                        prevText: 'Anterior',
                        nextText: 'Siguiente',
                        currentText: 'Hoy',
                    });
                })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( function() {
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                        changeMonth:true,
                        changeYear:true,
                        yearRange: "1990:2050", 
                        firstDay: 1,
                        minDate: 0,
                        
                         beforeShowDay: function (day) { 
                            var day = day.getDay(); 
                            if (day == 6 || day == 0) { 
                            return [false, "somecssclass"] 
                             } else { 
                                    return [true, "someothercssclass"] 
                                    } 
                            },
                          onSelect: function (date) {
                          $('#exampleModal').modal('show')
  /*
  if($("#nombre").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Nombre no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#nombre").focus();       // Esta función coloca el foco de escritura del usuario en el campo Nombre directamente.
        return false;
    }
    if($("#apellidos").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Apellidos no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#apellidos").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if($("#direccion").val() == ""){
        alert("El campo Dirección no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#direccion").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Checkbox
    if(!$("#mayor").is(":checked")){
        alert("Debe confirmar que es mayor de 18 años.");
        return false;
    }

    return true; // Si todo está correcto

    // Campos de texto
*/

                            },

                        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo',
                        'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
                        'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                        'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],

                        closeText: 'Cerrar',
                        prevText: 'Anterior',
                        nextText: 'Siguiente',
                        currentText: 'Hoy',
                    });
                })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Formulario con Ajax</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formdata">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"></br>
                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" required="required"></br>
                <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label><input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" required="required"></br>
                Género: <input type="radio" name="genero" id="hombre" checked="checked"><label for="hombre"> Hombre - </label><input type="radio" name="genero" id="mujer"><label for="mujer"> Mujer</label>
                <label for="mayor">Es mayor de 18 años: </label><input type="checkbox" name="mayor" id="mayor" required="required">
                <input type="button" id="botonenviar" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="exito" style="display:none">
            Sus datos han sido recibidos con éxito.
        </div>
        <div id="fracaso" style="display:none">
            Se ha producido un error durante el envío de datos.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hola, te recomiendo que uses boostrap, hay un componente que se llama modal, aquí puedes ver toda la documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#modalhide
De igual manera ya te deje el código para que lo pruebes pero tienes que mejorarlo haciendo las validaciones correspondientes.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado bastante. Una pregunta mas, como podria poner que de igual de la fecha en el formulario, me marque ya el dia que seleccione.

Comment: marcar en que sentido?

Comment: si , ves que al dar click en una fecha esta te dirige al formulario, si ese formulario tiene la parte de fecha; como hacer que al picar el dia este se muestre en ese campo de fecha. No se si me di a entender.